# Using sets as hyphotesis and goal in COQ

Tags: coq

How exactly could a proof like the following be completed?

```
1 subgoals
IHt1 : {t' : some_type | something_using t'}
IHt2 : {t' : some_type | something_else_using t'}
______________________________________(1/1)
{t' : some_type | another_thing_involving t'}
```

I do understand that the `{x|P x}` notation is a shorthand for the sig definition but I really cannot understand how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{x : D | P x}` is intuitively speaking the subset of the domain `D` containing the elements that satisfy the predicate `P`. As a proposition, it is true if that subset is non-empty, i.e. if there is a witness `x0` in `D` such that `P x0` is true.

An object of type `{x : D | P x}` is a pair containing an element `x0 : D` and a proof of `P x0`. This is visible when you look at the definition of `{x : D | P x}`, which is syntactic sugar for `sig (fun x:D => P x)`

```
Inductive sig (D:Type) (P:D -> Prop) : Type :=
    exist : forall x:D, P x -> sig P.
```

The type of the constructor is a dependent pair type; the first element of the pair has the type `D` and the second element has the type `P x` in which `x` is the first element.

To make use of a hypothesis of the form `{x : D | P x}`, the most basic way is to use the `destruct` tactic to break it down into its two components: a witness `x0 : D` and a proof `H : P x0`.

```
destruct IHt1.

1 subgoals
t' : some_type
H : something_using t'
IHt2 : {t'0 : some_type | something_else_using t'0}
______________________________________(1/1)
{t'0 : some_type | another_thing_involving t'0}
```

To prove a goal of the form `{x : D | P x}`, the most basic is to use the `exist` tactic to introduce the intended witness. This leaves one subgoal which is to prove that the witness has the desired property.

```
exists u.

⋮
______________________________________(1/1)
another_thing_involving u
```

Comment: Excellent answer and up to the point! Solved my problem, thanks a lot !